# How do I close Modal while clicking outside of the modal using jquery?

Tags: jquery

How do I close Modal while clicking outside of the modal using jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("body").click(function (e) {
    var x = e.pageX - e.target.offsetLeft;
    var y = e.pageY - e.target.offsetTop;

    if ((x < 75) || (x > 1275)) {

        $('.modal-backdrop').fadeOut();
        $('.modal').fadeOut("fast");
    }

});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with css, example:

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
window.onclick = function(event) {
   if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```